# Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException in ASP.NET 4.5.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, asp.net-4.5

I have asp.net application which is developed in asp.net 3.5 and i recently upgraded the application to new framework which is .NET Framework 4.5.1 and previously it was a web site and I converted it into Web Application now. Every things work fine expect one thing all I am facing below mentioned error on all those pages where Update Panel of Microsoft AJAX are used

Details of Error is:

```
Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: 
An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. 
The status code returned from the server was: 502
```

This is the error which is occurring when ever any event is trigger to update the update panel

While working in Visual Studio it is working fine but when i publish this web application and host it on IIS only than i encounter the error no matter on production server or on my dev machine. I have no idea what is wrong ...

Comment: Check http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx

Comment: this link doesn't helped me.it is releated to ParserErrorException and i am facing ServerErrorException.